# Codeigniter Datepicker in option selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, datepicker

I would like to show a `datepicker` if I click my dropdown option (created at only). And when I select a date, it will input it into the placeholder of the search bar. I tried numerous stuff but the datepicker wouldn't show up. This is my view.

```
 <div class="input-group">
  <select name="search_filter" id="search_filter">
    <option value="custid">Customer</option>
    <option value="orderno">Order no</option>
    <option id="datepicker" value="created_at">Created at</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="key" class="form-control" id="key" placeholder="<?php echo lang_key('Search');?>">
  <div class="input-group-addon search-plain" style="cursor:pointer;border-radius:0 5px 5px 0"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">       
  $(function() {
      $("#datepicker").datepicker({
          minDate : 0,
          dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
      });
  });
</script>
```

Can someone please tell me what I am missing? Thanks a lot in advance. I did include the href and script link for the datepicker. Sorry for the mess.

Comment: Why you want to have datepicker on a dropdown option?

Comment: can you create code snippet in fiddle?

Comment: Dont put the datepicker in the dropdown. Make it its own field

Comment: may this will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40657178/jquery-datepicker-appearing-after-one-option-is-selected